# android cursor order of operations

Tags: java, android, cursor

Is there a way to retrieve the raw query string being generated from a call like the following? I'm trying to figure out how the "?" placeholders get populated.

```
    Cursor cursor = database.query(
            adapter.getTable(),           // The table to query  - String
            adapter.getColumns(),         // The columns to return - String[]
            adapter.getWhereClause(),     // The columns for the WHERE clause - String
            adapter.getWhereClauseArgs(), // The values for the WHERE clause - String[]
            null,                         // Group by - String
            null,                         // Groups having - String
            adapter.getSortBy(),          // The sort order - String
            adapter.getLimit());          // The limit - String
```

I'm curious of the order of operations. For example, if the above query translated to the select below with the whereClause args below, would i get result1 or result2? Does it work like the order of operations in math, where statements in parenthesis get executed first? or does it strictly rely on the position of the "?"'s in the string.

```
    String select = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE someField = ? AND _id in(SELECT _id FROM table2 WHERE status = ?)";

    String[] args = new String[]{ "blue", "active" };

    String result1 = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE someField = 'blue' AND _id in(SELECT _id FROM table2 WHERE status = 'active')";

    String result2 = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE someField = 'active' AND _id in(SELECT _id FROM table2 WHERE status = 'blue')";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick test will show that it substitutes selection args by the position in the string, without any concept of order of operations.

Comment: How do you test that? See the actual query executed?

Comment: Well, you could run the query and see if it returns the results you want - that would certainly qualify as a test. If you pause the application with a debugger, you can also look at the returned `SQLiteCursor`'s private `mQuery` field, which stores the final executed query.